# laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0" install error

Tags: laravel-5.4

When i want install my laravel collective/HTML from CLI the below messahe has shown. Anyone please help me from fixed the problem.

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel>composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
The "ht//packagist/org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
htt/packagist/org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://packagist...org/p/laravelcollective/html%24b0b6819ee203fce431535a4549ba27ee52a7d77418c065c68b78577d198617e1.js
  on" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Comment: It feels like your firewall. I have tinywall installed and use that to monitor blocked network attempts.

Comment: my firewall is off and i have checked it.

Comment: Thankz a lot Alexx Roche..Finally problem solved by instaiing tinywall.. Again many many thankz..:)

Answer (score 0):

composer require 'laravelcollective/html:^5.4.0'

Worked for me.